# Prevent masonry grid from rearranging

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-masonry, masonry

I have a masonry grid setup with the packery layout which is totally fluid. However, on resizing the browser, the grid rearranges itself. I would like to keep the grid entirely static.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5gL8bz3e/1/

Here's my CSS:

```
body {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    }

.grid-item,
.grid-sizer {
    width: 5.3125vw;
    }

.gutter-sizer {
    width: 1vw;
    }

.grid-item {
    float: left;
    height: auto;
    background: #fff;
    border: 0px solid #fff;
    margin-bottom: 0vw;
    background: none;
    }

.grid-item img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: block;
    }

.grid-item--width2, .grid-item--width2b { width: 11.625vw; }
.grid-item--width4 { width: 24.25vw; }
.grid-item--width6 { width: 36.875vw; }

.grid {
    background: lightyellow;
    width: 75vw;
    position: relative;
    left: 12.625vw;
    top: 12.625vw;
    margin-top: 0;
    min-height: 1000px;
    }

.stamp {
    width: 11.625%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background: lightpink;
}

.stamp1 {
    left: 0;  
    }

.stamp2 {
    right: 0;
    }
```

HTML:

```
<div class="grid">
    <div class="gutter-sizer"></div>
    <div class="grid-sizer"></div>

    <div class="grid-item grid-item--width6">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/1180x760"/>
    </div>

    <div class="grid-item grid-item--width4">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/776x496"/>
    </div>

    <div class="grid-item grid-item--width2b">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/372x496"/>
    </div>

    <div class="grid-item grid-item--width2">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/372x232"/>
    </div>

    <div class="grid-item grid-item--width1">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/170x232"/>
    </div>

    <div class="grid-item grid-item--width1">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/170x232"/>
    </div>

        <div class="grid-item grid-item--width6">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/1180x760"/>
    </div>

    <div class="grid-item grid-item--width4">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/776x496"/>
    </div>

    <div class="grid-item grid-item--width2b">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/372x496"/>
    </div>

    <div class="grid-item grid-item--width2">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/372x232"/>
    </div>

    <div class="grid-item grid-item--width1">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/170x232"/>
    </div>

    <div class="grid-item grid-item--width1">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/170x232"/>
    </div>

       <div class="grid-item grid-item--width6">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/1180x760"/>
    </div>

    <div class="grid-item grid-item--width4">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/776x496"/>
    </div>

    <div class="grid-item grid-item--width2b">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/372x496"/>
    </div>

    <div class="grid-item grid-item--width2">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/372x232"/>
    </div>

    <div class="grid-item grid-item--width1">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/170x232"/>
    </div>

    <div class="grid-item grid-item--width1">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/170x232"/>
    </div>

        <div class="grid-item grid-item--width6">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/1180x760"/>
    </div>

    <div class="grid-item grid-item--width4">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/776x496"/>
    </div>

    <div class="grid-item grid-item--width2b">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/372x496"/>
    </div>

    <div class="grid-item grid-item--width2">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/372x232"/>
    </div>

    <div class="grid-item grid-item--width1">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/170x232"/>
    </div>

    <div class="grid-item grid-item--width1">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/170x232"/>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: That's what isotope masonry and packery layout are designed to do, rearrange the grid to fill the gaps. Consider fitRows instead.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the option `isResizeBound` will do just that. It is `true` by default but you could specify it otherwise.

```
var msnry = new Masonry('.grid', {
   columnWidth: 200,
   itemSelector: '.grid-item',
   isResizeBound: false
});
```

See the [doc](http://masonry.desandro.com/options.html#isresizebound) for more details.

Comment: I don't know if this quite works—when I add it to the JSFiddle and resize it breaks the gutter. I should also mention that it seems to generate a layout randomly depending on the screen size. I'd like to be able to configure one layout and not have it change ever.